# get url uptp required query string jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, query-string

Consider my url is like 
`http://localhost:4588/home?name=test&value=2003&view=current&index=1&....`

I need to take the url upto "view" querystring.

Is that possible in jQuery ?

**Edit:**

The 1st three values in url alone constant (name, value and view), after "view" it will change. So I need to take only upto "view" query string.

Comment: yes its possible, please show us what you have tried

Comment: The desired output is : `http://localhost:4588/home?
name=test&value=2003&view=current` ?

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui yes

Answer (score 3):

You can split the url using `split()`:

```js
var url = "http://localhost:4588/home?name=test&value=2003&view=current&index=1&....";
console.log(url.split('&index')[0])
```

**Explanation :**

`url.split('&index')` will return an `array` with 2 values:

`['http://localhost:4588/home?name=test&value=2003&view=current','=1&....']`, what you want here is only the first value (index of that value 0 [0]).

More about [split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp).

Comment: the 1st three values alone constant (name, value and view).. after "view" it will change.. so i couldn't take index[0].

Answer (score 0):

You can get it this way:

```js
var str = 'http://localhost:4588/home?name=test&value=2003&view=current&index=1&'

var pattern  = new RegExp(/view=[a-zA-Z0-9]*/); //this is the regex to find view=somevalue (where somevalue will have letters and numbers only

var i = pattern.exec(str); //this extracts the view=current string
console.log('matched view=current -->',i); 
console.log('search for index of view=current in our string',str.indexOf(i[0]));
console.log('length of view=current string-->' + i[0].length);

var final = str.substr(0, str.indexOf(i[0]) + i[0].length); // add the index  + the length of view=current and pass it as second argument to substring function
console.log(final);
```